# Error:ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, controls, mujoco

I wanted to call the function :
emptymatrix=np.zeros((sim.data.nv,sim.data.nv))
mjp.cymj._mj_fullM(model, emptymatrix, sim.data.qM)
in mujoco so that I can  Convert sparse inertia matrix M into full  matrix so that I can calclulate  the torque but I have this error:raceback (most recent call last):
File "kuka.py", line 58, in 
mjp.cymj._mj_fullM(sim.model,emptymatrix ,sim.data.qM)
File ".local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mujoco_py/generated/wrappers.pxi", line 5061, in mujoco_py.cymj._mj_fullM
ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)
If someone could help me I ll be so grateful.

Comment: Can you provide some code samples as well as what you have already tried to rectify the issue?

Comment: Your question is unreadable!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

mujoco_py's implementation of `mj_fullM` expects your `emptymatrix` to be a vector of length nv*nv, rather than a square matrix.

See these lines from [robosuite](https://github.com/ARISE-Initiative/robosuite/blob/874ce964640f66440a695582a1375df1aff247ac/robosuite/controllers/base_controller.py#L155):

```py
mass_matrix = np.ndarray(shape=(len(self.sim.data.qvel) ** 2,), dtype=np.float64, order="C")
mujoco_py.cymj._mj_fullM(self.sim.model, mass_matrix, self.sim.data.qM)
mass_matrix = np.reshape(mass_matrix, (len(self.sim.data.qvel), len(self.sim.data.qvel)))
self.mass_matrix = mass_matrix[self.qvel_index, :][:, self.qvel_index]
```

If you make use of the new MuJoCo python bindings (`pip install mujoco`), `mujoco.mj_fullM` takes the square matrix as you'd expect.